# Exception when starting jenkins EC2 instance on windows

Tags: jenkins

This is a common stack trace when attempting to create an EC2 windows slave on jenkins:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException: unexpected stream termination
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.<init>(Channel.java:260)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.<init>(Channel.java:208)
        at hudson.remoting.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:57)
        at hudson.remoting.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:43)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved by installing java and adding it to the PATH.